# Python Cookielib CookieJar, how can I read the response (html webpage) after sending a cookie -- WITHOUT using requests

Tags: python, cookies, response, cookielib, cookiejar

I'm working on a CTF and I've encountered a python challenge where I have to send a cookie named alien_id (which has a value between 1 and 75), to the url http://127.0.0.1:8082/cookiestore

I think I have managed to successfully send the cookie, however how can I read the webpage html response using cookielib, cookiejar. Note I can't use requests as this isn't available in the CTF.

```
  cj = CookieJar()
  c = Cookie(None, 'alien_id', x, '8082', True, 'http://127.0.0.1', 
   True, False, '/cookiestore', True, False, '1370002304', False, 'TestCookie', None, None, False)
  cj.set_cookie(c)
  print cj
```

This just outputs the following:

```
<CookieJar[<Cookie alien_id=11 for http://127.0.0.1:8082/cookiestore>]>
```

So is there a way using cookielib or cookiejar to read the html response after sending a cookie ?

Thanks so much :)

Comment: What do you mean by you can't use requests? why can't you use requests? you can add cookies with this

Comment: I can't use the python requests package. The python code runs on the ctf server. It gives me the error, package not found

Comment: @Reznik I can’t use the python requests package. The python code runs on the ctf server. It gives me the error package not found